# Question about singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

Lately I have been doing some examples and exercises about finding the singularities of a given function. What I noticed is that there was always only one singularity per function (if it even had a singularity).
So my questions is, can a complex function have more then one singularity?

My thoughts:
As far as I know:

> Let $f$ be analytic on the annulus $A$: $r_1 < |z-z_0| <r_2$ f can be
> expressed as
>
> (1) $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
>  \frac{b_n}{(z-z_0)^n}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^n$
>
> If a finite number of $b_n$ is nonzero, i.e. $b_k \neq 0$ and
> $b_{n}=0$  for all $n>k$ , then $z_0$ is a pole of order $k$.
>
> If all $b_n=0$ , then $z_0$ is a removable singularity.
>
> If an infinite number of $b_n \neq 0$, then $z_0$ is a essential
> singularity

If every function can be expressed like (1), then there should always be a max of one singularity.
Beacause even if we have two functions, $f$ and $g$ with singularities at different points $z_1$, $z_2$. Their sum $(f+g)$ can be expressed as (1). Is this correct?
If no, does anyone have an example with two singularities, and how its Laurent series looks like.

Comment: $1/z+1/(1-z)$ which has Laurent series $1/z +\sum z^n$ around zero (more precisely on $|z|<1$; by doing $1-z=u$ one can easily construct the Laurent series around $1$ too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why should a function only have one singularity? Consider $z\mapsto\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{1+z}$; consider the Gamma function; there are infinitely many counterexamples. A function may have countably many singularities, and be analytic everywhere else.

Your confusion lies in misinterpreting what the Laurent series theorem is saying. It is not saying there is at most one singularity; rather, it is saying that if you have an *isolated* singularity, there is a (*potentially small*) annulus about the singularity in which a valid analytic series expansion holds.

"Let $f$ be analytic on the annulus $r_1\lt|z-z_0|\lt r_2$": $f$ **must** be analytic for this to hold. So, if $f$ has multiple singularities, and they are all isolated, I can simply just find an $r_2$ so small that *no other singularities of $f$ are present in $A$*. This is no contradiction.

For instance, $z\mapsto\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z+1}$ does not have a valid Laurent series on the annulus $1/2\lt|z|\lt2$ since $z=-1$ is another singularity contained in this annulus. However, it has a valid Laurent series on the annulus $1/2\lt|z|\lt3/4$... and also on $2\lt|z|\lt10$ (these numbers are arbitrary and only for demonstrative purpose) since in both cases there are no singularities within the annulus itself. In the second annulus you could consider it a Laurent series about $z=-1$ or about $z=0$ - it makes no matter, as both are inclosed in the interior.

Comment: Another question, if I want to calculate the Laurent series about $z=0$, can I then just look at $\frac{1}{z}$, or do I have to consider the whole function $\frac{1}{z}+ \frac{1}{z+1}$?

Comment: You have to look at the whole function, in a sense. However, you can combine - a Laurent series of $1/z$ about $z=0$ combined with a standard power series of $1/(z+1)$ about $z=0$ will sum to make the Laurent series of $1/z+1/(z+1)$ @Andres2003 I am pretty sure.